# TabTip click &123 key programmatically

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a C# winForms application that makes use of the Windows 8 keyboard.

I open the keyboard by launching tabtip.exe.

I am able to close the keyboard using a PostMessage command like this:

```
public static void HideOnScreenKeyboard()
{
    uint WM_SYSCOMMAND = 274;
    uint SC_CLOSE = 61536;
    IntPtr KeyboardWnd = FindWindow("IPTip_Main_Window", null);
    PostMessage(KeyboardWnd.ToInt32(), WM_SYSCOMMAND, (int)SC_CLOSE, 0);
}
```

I think using PostMessage it should be possible to simulate almost anything programmatically if you just pass the correct values.

The values used for closing the keyboard (274 and 61536) I just found on the internet.

It looks that it is possible to grab these values using Spy++, or some other tools but I am unable how to do this.

Can anybody tell me the values needed to simulate a press on the &123 key, so the keyboard switches to the numeric keyboard?

Or, does anybody know how to get these values?

I have tried Spy++, but so many messages are passing constantly that I don't know where to look.

Look at the image of the OnScreenKeyboard to see what key I mean

[image: Tabtip keyboard &123]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to use [SendInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310(v=vs.85).aspx) to simulate a mouse click event on the &123 button of the virtual keyboard window.

Below is an example of how to use SendInput to send a mouse click (left_down + left_up) to the button but I haven't included the code to programatically find the window and get the window size.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct MINPUT
{
  internal uint type;
  internal short dx;
  internal short dy;
  internal ushort mouseData;
  internal ushort dwFlags;
  internal ushort time;
  internal IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
  internal static int Size
  {
     get { return Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(INPUT)); }
  }
}      

const ushort MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE = 0x8000;
const ushort MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x0002;
const ushort MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x0004;

// programatically determine the position and size of the TabTip window
// compute the location of the center of the &123 key
int coordinateX = ...
int coordinateY = ...

var pInputs = new[] { 
                new MINPUT() {
                     type = 0×01; //INPUT_KEYBOARD                         
                     dx = coordinateX,
                     dy = coordinateY;
                     dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN;
                     time = 0;
                     dwExtraInfo = IntPtr.Zero;
                },
                new MINPUT() {
                     type = 0×01; //INPUT_KEYBOARD
                     dx = coordinateX,
                     dy = coordinateY;
                     dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP;
                     time = 0;
                     dwExtraInfo = IntPtr.Zero;
               }
};

SendInput((uint)pInputs.Length, pInputs, MINPUT.Size);
```

Comment: Hi Miky,

I don't think this is answer to my question.
On Windows 8 when you run TabTip.exe an On Screen Keyboard pops up.
This has a &123 key I want to press.

I added an image to my original questions to make the question more clear.

Comment: You're right.. it seems I misunderstood your question

Comment: How about using a mouse event instead. You can use SendInput to simulate a mouse click and determine the coordinates of the &123 key programatically, based on the location of the TabTip window..

Comment: This does work but not really the desired effect.
Now the keyboard pops in alphanumeric, and then I simulate the mousepress and then the keyboard switches to numeric.

So the user can see the swapping. Not really desired. 

But that would be the same with how I wanted to solve it so your answer is valid.

I will just drop this from my app, so the users must manually switch to numeric keyboard if desired.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you set the input scope of the edit control to numeric? New built-in edit controls with the correct properties automatically trigger the numeric mode when touched.

Rather than hacking the Touch Input Panel which appears differently in different locales, etc. set `InputScope` of the text box to `Number` and let Windows do the magic.